# representative diagram of .net framework Bace class library for better understanding of Types and Members Cooperations

Tags: .net, visual-studio, uml, class-diagram, object-diagram

Is it possible to get any representative diagram (such as object diagram or class diagram)
from .Net types of a name space. The diagram could represent the relations and dependencies between the .Net types and members, and we could understand better the structure of portion of a namespace. instead of looking at MSDN texts.

For example, I like to know the organization of `system.configuration` namespace important members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hi

### I found the way It wasnt Complicated:

1-creat a Visual studio project such as console or winform or ..

2-add a class diagram to the project

3-go to View--->class view,now you can see class view panel

4-exapand the Project refrence node.
and you can find .net dlls that your project refers to them

5-Now Drag your favorite dll into class diagram Editor

6-now you have a high level schema from inside of the dll

and you have options to Rearange them and wok with the dagram
but there is one thing,It seems that  we could only see The Association Relation and
unfortunately thers not more details such as aggregation and ...

i think there must be some advanced tools 
and helpful utilities that enhance working with diagram 
its great anyone could help and introduce them

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has published (non-UML) overviews of the BCL in the past (have a hunt around on http://download.microsoft.com), but those have always been very high level.

In practice the number of types that the BCL defines (let alone the whole framework) is in the thousands and therefore beyond anything more detailed in a single diagram.

Comment: ye ,i know ,its not possible to make a diagram that covers all the details,and of course i dont want it,but its good if u want to know more about some portion of a Name space and understand more about the design ,u could make a diagram ,i think its possible becouse of refactoring